# Output a New Line Character in a String to Word with Powershell

Tags: powershell, docx

I am authoring a docx file in Powershell and I am outputting using TypeText() to a Selection from a Word.Application object and TypeParagraph() for a new line and this is working fine.

My question is how do I do a new line mid string?

I will need both return and shift + return.

Thanks in advance,
Norman

**EDIT:**
Here is a basic script.

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $True 

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Test\Template.docx")
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection
$a = $objSelection.EndKey(6, 0)

$text = "Shift + enter that works`vThanks Dangph"
$objSelection.TypeText($text)
$objSelection.TypeParagraph()
$text = "Enter that`r`nworks"
$objSelection.TypeText($text)
$objSelection.TypeParagraph()
```

While knocking the above up I have realised that the issue with `r`n that I had is actually an issue with Selection.Find.Execute. I will raise this as a separate question.

So in short `v for shift + enter and `r`n for enter.

Comment: You should give us a minimal working script to test with. I'm not going to write a script myself just to answer your question, so I can't test this, but it seems that a line break is done in Word with a vertical tab, which is represented in PowerShell as `"\`v"`. Try doing TypeText with this: `"hello\`vthere"` (make sure to use double quotes and not single quotes).

Comment: @Dangph - Please see the edit above. If you submit an answer as above I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a line break is done in Word with a vertical tab, which is represented in PowerShell as:

```
"`v"
```

Try doing a `TypeText` with this:

```
"hello`vthere"
```

(Make sure to use double quotes and not single quotes.)